# How to read and write to a text file using python while deploying on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, text-files

I use a bot that writes (file ids) of the files that sent from user to a text file and then read from this text file the (file ids) then send it back to the user.The method worked, but when I deploy it to Heroku, I can no longer see, process, or download the text file.

Is there a way to view the text files that we deploy to heroku? Or is there a way to upload the text files on a cloud website and then make the bot open (read & write) the text file using the text file URL (but I think this would allow any user on the internet to access and modify my text files, which means it is not safe)? Create SQL database and upload text files and link each text file with its own URL (But I'm new to SQL)?

Is there any other simple method to solve this problem? What do you advise me to do in this case?

https://github.com/zieadshabkalieh/a

NOTE: The text file in my code named first.txt

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Answer (score 2):

Heroku has an [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) filesystem: every file created by the application will be removed (also any change to existing files deployed with the application) when there is a new deployment or application restart.
Heroku Dynos also restart every 24 hours.

It is a good idea to persist data to a remote storage (like S3) or a DB (always a good option but requires a little bit more work).

For reading/writing simple files you can check [HerokuFiles](https://github.com/gcatanese/HerokuFiles) repository with some Python examples and options. I would suggest S3 (using Python boto module) as it is easy to use, even if the number/size of files will one day increase.